# How to prevent truncated error bars in plotly stacked bar chart error bars?

Tags: plotly, plotly-python

When I’m plotting a stacked bar chart with error bars in plotly, I have the problem that the upper parts of the error bars are covered by the shape element of the above bar chart (see screenshot).

[image]

I found [this solution](https://community.plotly.com/t/stacked-bar-chart-with-calculated-mean-and-sem/47672) from the official plotly forums which is quite unwieldy.

Is there a better solution to this problem?

Thanks a lot for any input.

Comment: I personally didn't see any further improvement, given that the discussion has been closed by the community in the question. The only other thing that could be done would be to create a bar chart and error bars, if all the giving of error bars could be put into a loop process.